Beau­tiful Racket expander unit testing
I'm evaluating Beau­tiful Racket book and can't understand how can I unit test my expander.
I see in https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/the-expander.html as an example that I can create file with
#lang reader "stacker.rkt"
at the begin and run this file with DrRacket.
But how can I create unit test that can read and check execution of my dsl in file or string?
